# Creating graphics region

Tags: c#, graphics, user-controls, gdi+

I want to create a drawable region within a user control of the following dimensions:

`x=0, y=100, width=(UserControl.Width), height=(UserControl.Height-100)`.

The reason for this is so that the client area of the region starts at 0,0 and would help to make it easier to draw shapes relative to the client region and not have to worry about subtracting 100 from the height.

As I am drawing directly on the user control using C# and Visual Studio 2012, is there any built-in class that I can use to create a client region that can be draw on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, 100) in your paint event handler to offset the drawing.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  The 100 pixels that was transformed seems to grow larger when the form is maximized.  I need the top portion of the user control to be fixed at 100px height.

Comment: I can't make sense of that comment, nothing gets "transformed" when you maximize a form and pixels don't get larger.  The position of a user control is determined by its Location property.  Do absolutely make sure that you only ever paint in the Paint event handler, never use CreateGraphics().

Comment: I am actually using the Paint handler, however I've found out why the "transformed" part was changing size.  It was a code error causing a rectangle to have a negative Y-point causing it to move up the screen.  I will accept your answer.